# Is it possible to create a Gmail filter "unless"?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I use subadressing in Gmail to tag incoming message, something like name+abc@gmail.com.

Now I want to filter all messages that contains `ABC` in the body but if I make a naive search for that string all messages that are addressed to name+abc@gmail.com are also found. I want to exclude all messages that ONLY contains ABC in to/cc/bcc and ONLY find those messages that contains that string in their body.

If I do `-to:abc AND abc` messages to:abc are excluded even if they also contains abc in the body.

I can't wrap my head around the booleans here. Does this make sense:

if (to:abc AND not body:abc) exclude
if (to:abc AND body:abc) include
if (not to:abc) AND (body:abc) include

Is that possible to construct in Gmail?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do this in Gmail

Gmail searches do not provide `BODY` as a search parameter.

Gmail searches do not provide `unless` as a search parameter.

To solve your problem you need to rethink your search approach and/or your plus labelling approach.

Example: Instead of seeding your plus address with potential search terms, use either nonsensical terms (name+**zy06**@gmail.com) or alternatively add a delimiter(s)
(name+labc@gmail.com; name+labcl@gmail.com).  Neither `labc`, `labcl`,  nor `zy06` will be found by search term `+abc`.

**See:** [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190)